# How is performance affected by an unused using directive?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, using

Visual Studio will automatically create using statements for you whenever you create a new page or project. Some of these you will never use.

Visual Studio has the useful feature to "remove unused usings".

I wonder if there is any negative effect on program performance if the using statements which are never accessed, remain mentioned at the top of the file.

Comment: I did search for it before asking, and it didn't show up.

Comment: FWIW, this posting has better SEO: it was the first result in Google for me. Of the 2 originals linked, one is unavailable (removed) and the other is worded differently enough to add some value to this post, even if just as a redirection.

Comment: @DaveD first for you because Google knows your exact preferences and search history. In my friend's computer was not the first.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

An unused using has no impact to the runtime performance of your application.

It can affect the performance of the IDE and the overall compilation phase.  The reason why is that it creates an additional namespace in which name resolution must occur.  However these tend to be minor and shouldn't have a noticeable impact on your IDE experience for most scenarios.

It can also affect the performance of evaluating expressions in the debugger for the same reasons.

Comment: The more usings there are, the slower Intellisense will be

Answer (score 16):

No, it's just a compile-time/coding style thing. .NET binaries use fully qualified names under the hood.

Comment: Does this mean that longer class and method names have a small but actual (if immeasurable) impact on JIT compilation times?

Answer (score 16):

The following link [A good read on why to remove unused references](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/visual-studio---why-should-i-remove-unused-references-/6102) explains how it be useful to remove unused references from the application.

Below are the some excerpts from the link:

1. By removing any unused references in your application, you are
   preventing the `CLR` from loading the unused referenced modules at
   runtime. Which means that you will reduce the startup time of your
   application, because it takes time to load each module and avoids
   having the compiler load metadata that will never be used. You may
   find that depending on the size of each library, your startup time
   is noticeably reduced. This isn't to say that your application will
   be faster once loaded, but it can be pretty handy to know that your
   startup time might get reduced.
2. Another benefit of removing any unused references is that you will
       reduce the risk of conflicts with namespaces. For example, if you
       have both `System.Drawing` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls` referenced,
       you might find that you get conflicts when trying to reference the
       `Image` class. If you have using directives in your class that match
       these references, the compiler can't tell which of the ones to use.
       If you regularly use autocomplete when developing, removing unused
       namespaces will reduce the number of autocompletion values in your
       text editor as you type.

Comment: 1. contradicts all the other answers. So I guess it is not true or not relevant? Could somebody confirm who really knows?

Answer (score 8):

No effect on execution speed, but there may be some slight effect on compilation speed/intellisense as there are more potential namespaces to search for the proper class.  I wouldn't worry too much about it, but you can use the Organize Usings menu item to remove and sort the using statements.

Answer (score 6):

Code that does not execute does not affect the performance of a program.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are several process involved when compiling a program.  When the compiler start looking for references (classes, methods) it will use only the ones used on the code.  The using directive only tells the compiler where to look.  A lot of unused using statement could maybe have a performance issue but just at compile time.  At runtime, all the outside code is properly linked or included as part of the binary.