# Unused using statements

Tags: c#, optimization, using

I may already know the answer to this question, but I thought it was worth asking anyway. If I have a load of `using` statements within my code file that *aren't* being used;

1. Does that have any sort of detrimental performance impact?
2. How does the compiler deal with them at compile/run time?

Thanks

Comment: You're talking about using **directives** or using **statements** ?

Comment: Do you mean runtime performances or compiler performance? The compiler doesn't deal with them at runtime, by definition.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136278/why-should-you-remove-unnecessary-c-using-directives ?

Comment: using statements, also im talking about runtime performance rather than compile time performance

Comment: @Jon - there is no such thing as an "unused using statement"... I assume you mean things like "`using System.Xml;`" - that is a *directive*. The *statement* is "`using(var conn = CreateConnection()) {...}`"

Comment: @Marc, my bad...i thought my question way pretty straight forward..but i guess not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> does that have any sort of detrimental performance impact?

No.

> How does the compiler deal with them at compile/run time?

At compile time they do what you'd expect, i.e. act as namespace imports. They don't appear in the compiled binary: any reference to a type uses the fully-qualified name.

The compiler does check the namespace in a `using` statement even if it's not needed; if you remove a namespace, then all the `using` statements that refer to it will fail.

To me, redundant `using` statements are like redundant comments. They make no difference to the compiler, but include too many of them, and you risk confusing your developers.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't affect performance at **runtime at all**.

It will probably increase compile-time very slightly since:

1) The compiler needs to parse a few more characters
2) It has to look up identifiers among more candidates. But since this probably uses hashtables it shouldn't be expensive either.

I'd guess the **compiler slowdown is negligible**.

I'd guess it slows Intellisense down a bit more since the list it has to display and filter gets quite a bit longer.

Removing unused usings is more a stylistic than a performance improvement. And you need to be careful about extension methods since they are brought into scope by using statements. For example I don't remove `using System.Linq` even when it's currently unused.

Comment: Not exactly related, but could you please explain more why you wouldn't want to remove `using System.Linq` ?  I am not exactly following.

Comment: @Roman Because I like having LINQ methods shown in Intellisense.

Comment: Yes, probably the Intellisense infrastructure is the only one that could be talk about performances with unused usings.

Answer (score 2):

No performance impact in run time. However, a lot of namespaces can somewhat slow down your code completion and decrease productivity

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance hit at runtime, usings are resolved at compile time and useless ones are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It has no impact at all - see response to this question:

[How is performance affected by an unused using directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162766/how-is-performance-affected-by-an-unused-using-statement)

Answer (score 0):

It may make the compile time longer, but it will have either no or a negligible effect on run-time performance.