# Using Statements in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good programming habits questions.  Do additional using statements that the Class does not use affect the speed of the application?

Example I have a Class called StoreController -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

However, it only needs

```
using System.Web.Mvc; //Love some Resharerper
```

My question still, does it really affect the application to have the unused using statements?

Comment: No, there is no performance impact.

Comment: Those are [using directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). C# *has* a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) but it's something different. It helps, when there are two features that use the same keyword, to use the correct terminology.

Comment: I think it might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026820/do-unused-usings-in-net-affect-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no impact at runtime, however having a bunch of useless text in the screen bothers your fellow developers. Remove unused `Usings`, always.

**Edit:** `using System.Linq;` is to C# as air breathing is to humans. Leave it there always, even if it's not being used at present.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have excluded that namespace from R#'s "Removed Unused Usings" feature in my Visual Studio =)

Comment: +1 for System.Linq. Removing it is to be considered heresy.

Answer (score 1):

Grant's comment is the correct. The using directives are used during compilation to determine the correct type references. They do not affect application execution.