# is "using" slower than direct referencing to the name space in winrt?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

we have two ways of coding. Which one is the better approach?

```
var visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

or

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
var visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is performance affected by an unused using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162766/how-is-performance-affected-by-an-unused-using-statement)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026820/do-unused-usings-in-net-affect-performance?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162766/how-is-performance-affected-by-an-unused-using-statement

Answer (score 2):

No. It makes no difference<sup>1</sup>

The compiled code is the same. The [using Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) merely instructs the *compiler* how to resolve the types used.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is true of C#; WinRT or WPF or XAML does not change this.